# Does this cause a PHP memory leak?

Tags: php

Does this cause a PHP memory leak?

```
function xml_parse($xmlString)
{
    return json_decode(json_encode(new SimpleXMLElement($xmlString)), true);
}
```

Or do i need to unset the SimpleXML obj like this?

```
function xml_parse($xmlString)
{
    $sObj = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlString);
    $ret  = json_decode(json_encode($sObj), true);
    unset($sObj);
    return $ret;
}
```

I am running this in a large foreach as the script needs to parse lots of files.

Comment: Looks like https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62468

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to know, run it a couple thousand times and output the memory usage. Normally, unused objects will be cleaned up by the garbage collector, so the first snippet wouldn't 'leak' memory. However, in PHP <5.3 there is an issue with circular references which can prevent unused objects from being collected. So if you do experience an issue, updating PHP might solve it for you.

Comment: I did 2 test runs and with first method i got around 400Mb while with second method i got to about 270Mb. On PHP5.3.6 (MAMP)

Answer (score 1):

I'm no uber PHP guru, but I would probably go with the second example you have there, just to be safe.

Answer (score 1):

It will not cause a memory leak. PHP's garbage collector will see that there's no references left to the SimpleXMLElement and remove it as needed.